# Upgrading from Plone 3.3.6 to Plone 4.2.1 ... is blobstorage in use?

Tags: plone

Plone Experts:

I inherited a Plone site running Plone 3.3.1.  It has a Data.fs size of about 1 GB.  It seemed reasonable to try to take advantage of newer features and, in particular, of blobstorage by upgrading to Plone 4.

Thus far I've successfully upgraded from Plone 3.3.1 to Plone 3.3.6 including appropriate data migration for our production usage.

Next, on a RH Linux development server, I did a fresh UnifiedInstall of Plone 4.2.1 which went smoothly.  We have virtually no third-party or add-on packages to this is should be a comparatively "vanilla" installation.
Then, I copied in the Data.fs from the Plone 3.3.6 install and did the portal migration step to upgrade from 3.3.6 to 4.2.1.
That also seemed to go smoothly and I can see that I've got many files now in var/blobstorage that seem to be consuming something like 750 MB of space.  Great, I thought!

However, the size of Data.fs still still seems to be very close to 1 GB.

So, did the portal migration step create blobstorage but I failed to do something that allows my site to begin to actually use the blobstorage?  Or is there something that I need to do to "trim" Data.fs so that it no longer contains the content that has been moved to blobstorage? (Note: I did do a pack of Data.fs but with no significant reduction in the file size)  Is there a log file that I can examine that would tell me if I'm using the content in blobstorage?

Thanks for your consideration,

John

Note: as is likely obvious from my question, I'm a Plone neophyte.  I'm working on Martin Aspeli's Professional Plone 4 Development book, but haven't found the answer to my questions either in there or in searches of various fora.

Answer (score 3):

the default zeopack configuration only trims objects greater than a day old. If you just ran the migration, likely all those objects are not going to be packed. You can either customize the recipe to retain a different amount of days(0) or just customize the zeopack script directly and then retry packing.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zeoserver

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct.  Changing the setting in /Control_Panel/Database/main to zero days and re-packing reduced the size of Data.fs from about 960 MB to about 130 MB.  The Unix command 'du -sk' run against var/blobstorage tells me that there is about 780 MB of data in blobstorage so this all seems quite reasonable.  I appreciate your help and timely response.  -- John